# Show a hierarchy of posts with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a simple thread/discussion mechanism, but I'm having a hard time to create a query that will retrieve my posts like a tree/hierarchy of posts.

I have a POSTS table with the following attributes (simplified): id, text, username, type, replytoid

type: 'THREAD START' or 'REPLY'
replytoid: The comment is replying another comment, so I store here the 'parent' id. The 'THREAD START' has a NULL replytoid.

My test data is: ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b194/2))

```
| ID |             TEXT | USERNAME |                 TYPE | REPLYTOID |
|----|------------------|----------|----------------------|-----------|
|  1 | My name is Alice |    Alice | THREAD START         |    (null) |
|  2 |  Reply to @Alice |      Bob | REPLY                |         1 |
|  3 |    Reply to @Bob |    Carol | REPLY                |         2 |
|  4 |  Reply to @Carol |     Dave | REPLY                |         3 |
|  5 |  Reply to @Alice |      Eve | REPLY                |         1 |
|  6 | My name is Frank |    Frank | THREAD START         |    (null) |
|  7 |  Reply to @Frank |     Gina | REPLY                |         6 |
```

I've tried many kinds of JOINs, but I can't achieve my expected output, that is:

```
| ID |             TEXT | USERNAME |            TYPE | REPLYTOID | LEVEL | THREADID |
|----|------------------|----------|-----------------|-----------|-------|----------|
|  1 | My name is Alice |    Alice | THREAD START    |    (null) |     1 |        1 |
|  2 |  Reply to @Alice |      Bob | REPLY           |         1 |     2 |        1 |
|  5 |  Reply to @Alice |      Eve | REPLY           |         1 |     2 |        1 |
|  3 |    Reply to @Bob |    Carol | REPLY           |         2 |     3 |        1 |
|  4 |  Reply to @Carol |     Dave | REPLY           |         3 |     4 |        1 |
|  6 | My name is Frank |    Frank | THREAD START    |    (null) |     1 |        6 |
|  7 |  Reply to @Frank |     Gina | REPLY           |         6 |     2 |        6 |
```

Comment: You mean just add Level And ThreadID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of a problem where you can use recursive CTE. Start with root posts as anchor and build up the replies linking them to parents. You can get the level by increasing the previous level and thread by preserving the parent id.

```
with cte as
(
  select *, 1 as level, id as thread
  from posts
  where replytoid is null

  union all

  select posts.*, cte.level + 1 as level, cte.thread 
  from posts
  inner join cte on cte.id = posts.replytoid
)

select * from cte
order by thread, level
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b194/6)